# How can I customize Cloud Run application URL?

Tags: google-cloud-run

If you run an application on Cloud Run and deployed container by opening *this URL* in a web browser the URL comes like this:

**this_cloud_run_format.run.app**

Can this URL be customized and how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google Cloud Run does not support changing the auto-generated service URL.

You can set up a custom domain using Cloud Run Domain Mapping.

[Mapping custom domains](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/mapping-custom-domains)

You will need to own/control the domain and be able to create resource records at the authoritative name servers (DNS server) for the domain.